Case sensitivity in existing Entity Framework Core migrations
I created an entity model where some properties and entity names contained casing errors. I used Entity Framework Core 6.0.32.
As the entity model evolved I created more migrations:
MigrationA, MigrationB, MigrationC

Then I was tasked to fix the wrong casing in the property names of the entities.
What I did I renamed the property names and (unfortunately) manually fixed casings in the existing migrations. Now I have issues creating a new migration with new entities because one renamed property can not be found (don't know if there will be more errors once the first is gone).
The error I get is:

Navigation 'Project.EFC.Entities.RenamedEntity (Dictionary<string, object>).RenamedProperty' was not found. Please add the navigation to the entity type before configuring it.


RenamedEntity and RenamedProperty exist in the exact casing as displayed
But RenamedProperty is a navigation property of type list and not a dictionary

So my question:
if I only change the casing of entity names and properties will I have to manually touch the existing migrations? (At the DB table names and column names should not change, only the entity namings).

What’s your DB collation? I would suggest to revert the manual changes and create new migration for renaming and all…

You never touch existing migrations "after the fact". If you need to change something they did, you create a new migration that does the change. If you force-change an existing migration after it has been applied ... I don't know. The probability something or everything will blow up in your face are >> 0. There might be a chance to fix the situation, though if you do what Vivek suggests above.

@Fildor At the first look it seemed easier since to rename the existing migrations than organizing a DB update for a new migration.

Yes, but that's not how that works. Changing the code of your migrations doesn't magically make a leap to the past and retro-actively changes past changes. -- again: given they have been applied. Of course there are edge cases, where you may be able to correct little mistakes before they go productive. I am speaking "in general" here.

And I also renamed the DbContext, so I had to touch them anyway it seems:
And just to make sure: yes, I know it was a studip idea.
